How to align components in Altium designer?
I am completely new at PCB design, finally finished the schematic and component search, you guys may have seen my last manic questions. Figuring out how to do the simplest things like delete a 3D model from a footprint (I couldn't figure it out i just changed it to a tiny cylinder) and how to attach a 3D model to a footprint has taken so much time to try and figure out. So I come to the experts for advice or answers.
My question:
How would I go about aligning a component so that the center of it is at the exact coordinate I designate? You can see I have the guidelines so that they intersect at that point. I need to do these alignments for quite a few parts so I would need to learn to how to align these parts at certain x and y distances from the origin I have calculated?


Highlight the component of interest and type in the coordinates under the General tab, Location. If the General tab isn't visible, activate it under Panels menu (lower right button), Properties. You can also lock the position of the component so you don't accidentally move it whilst moving other parts.
When you create footprints, be sure to set the reference location. This is found under Edit, Set Reference when editing the footprint library. You have a choice of setting the location to pin-1, center of the pad array, or a custom location. And, yes, do learn how to create your own footprints.
You can also enter coordinates in the PCB List panel, also found under the Panels menu.
Also learn to use the functions under Edit, Align which allows you to align components with respect to other components.

Thank you qrk, will try and do this today. Hopefully get the layout and project done today!!!
